# Form Submission using Ajax - Which is the correct way?

Tags: jquery

I am seeing two methods being used to submit form via ajax. Which one is valid? If the first one is, how come it's not making use of $ajax?

Method 1:

```
    $(form).on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).serialize();
    });
```

Method 2:

```
$(function() {
$(form).on("submit", function (event) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "pathscript.php",
      data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {

    }).fail(function() {

    });
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
  });
})
```

Comment: nice, try saving your form data in a `var formData` before the ajax. (e.g. `var formData = $(this).serialize();` then do the ajax with `data: formData`)

Answer (score 2):

Method 1 doesn't send any request and form won't be submitted. 
Method 2 is the way you should do it.

```
$(this).serialize();
```

This will just serialize your from content.

So as the final conclusion Method to is the correct way and only it is doing the AJAX form submit.

Comment: if we remove event.preventDefault() from Method 1, even then it won;t submit?

Comment: without `preventDefault` the form will be submitted

Comment: the second, as the answer says

Comment: @Thomasmkov , please accept the answer since it is complete and correct.